# Safari accessibility issue - tabIndex on a href links is not working in Safari even if enabled in settings (Anchor tags are ignored by Safari)

Tags: safari, accessibility, tabindex

Anchor tags are ignored by Safari.

In this example `<a>` is focusable in browsers except for Safari:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-merkle-1gvoq

It does not show the border around the `<a>` element. However, the `onFocus` event is firing.

If I add tabIndex={0} to an internal element, it can solve the issue but does not seem to be a good solution. And a user has to press a Tab key twice.

Example with tabIndex={0} on internal element:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-tesla-59qsy

In Safari settings the Tab key is configured to make every element tabbable.

Any ideas?

P.S. Updated 1st version by adding role="presentation" to SVG. Still not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Safari does not apply CSS styles to an `<A>` element inside SVG.

One of the possible solutions can be adding the class to a child element and drawing a border on that element.

Here is the updated version: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-goodall-g7sty

If there are any other solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Your stuff is inside an SVG with `role="img"`, that tells the accessibility tree "nothing interactive in here". If it's interactive, you need an operable role.

Comment: Updated. But still not working even with role="presentation"